# How to get Match Groups in ruby like Rubular without spliting the string

Tags: ruby, regex, rubular, named-captures

How does Rubular ([Example](http://rubular.com/r/iJ1eJ1zpHs)) get the match groups?

```
/regex(?<named> .*)/.match('some long string')
```

[match](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-match) method (in example) only returns the first match.

[scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan) method returns an array without named captures.

What is the best way to get an array of named captures (no splitting)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've always assumed that Rubular works something like this:

```
matches = []

"foobar foobaz fooqux".scan(/foo(?<named>\w+)/) do
  matches << Regexp.last_match
end

p matches
# => [ #<MatchData "foobar" named:"bar">,
#      #<MatchData "foobaz" named:"baz">,
#      #<MatchData "fooqux" named:"qux"> ]
```

If we use `enum_for` and `$~` (an alias for `Regexp.last_match`) we can make it a bit more Rubyish:

```
matches = "foobar foobaz fooqux".enum_for(:scan, /foo(?<named>\w+)/).map { $~ }
```